# Find $f'(t)$, where $f(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\cos(xt)dx$

Tags: integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

> Let $f(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\cos(xt)dx.$ Fine $f'(t).$

I thought about two different approach. I think my first solution is accurate, but I would like to work on the second solution and have a precise argument based on epsilon, I appreciate if you help me.

$\mathbf{My\: frist\: solution:}$

Add $i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\sin(xt)dx$, so we have

$$f(t)=\Re{(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2+ixt}}dx)=\Re(e^{-\frac{t^2}{4}}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-(x-\frac{it}{2})^2}dx).$$
Hence $$f(t)=\sqrt{\pi}\exp{\{-\frac{t^2}{4}}\}$$
and so 
$$f'(t)=-\frac{\sqrt{\pi }t}{2}\exp{\{-\frac{t^2}{4}}\}$$.

$\mathbf{Second\: solution}$

By Leibniz integral rule, I know

$$f'(t)=-2\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-x^2}\sin{(xt)}dx$$.

Define $g(t)=-2\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-x^2}\sin{(xt)}dx$

Given $\epsilon$, we need to find $h$ sufficiency small such that we have

$$|\frac{f(t+h)-f(t)}{h}-g(t)|\leq \epsilon$$.

By definition of $f$ and $g$ we have have the following

$$|\frac{f(t+h)-f(t)}{h}-g(t)|=2|\int^{\infty}_0e^{-x^2}\big{(}\frac{\cos(x(t+h))-\cos(tx)}{h}+x\sin(xt))dx|$$

AS $$\frac{d}{dt}(\cos{xt})=-x\sin{(xt)}$$

for the $\epsilon$, there exsist $h$ small enough such that

$$|\frac{\cos{(xt+xh)}-\cos{xt}}{h}+x\sin{(xt)}|\leq \epsilon$$

Hence

$$2|\int^{\infty}_0e^{-x^2}\big{(}\frac{\cos(x(t+h))-\cos(tx)}{h}+x\sin(xt))dx|\leq 2\epsilon\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt{\pi}\epsilon,$$

which shows that $f'(t)=-2\int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-x^2}\sin{(xt)}dx.$

Comment: One issue in your second solution is that $h$ depends on $x$.

Comment: How do you differentiate $\exp(-t^2/4)$ and get $-(\sqrt t/2)\exp(-t^2/4)$?

Comment: additionally in your first solution, be sure to justify the complex change of variables in evaluating the Gaussian; I have been chastised for this and am passing it on

Comment: I also suggest ( to go further but you may have noticed it ) that an integration by part $u'=xe^{-x^2}$ and $v=\sin\left(xt\right)$ would help you find explicitely $f$ using a differential equation.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net  Would you mind to explain what my mistake is. I didn't understand your comment. I thought that is only the definition of of $\frac{d}{dt}\cos(xt)$, so $h $ is independent of $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace $\cos(xt)$ by $\frac{e^{ixt}+e^{-ixt}}{2}$ and look at
$$h(a) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}e^{2ax} dx $$

In your second part you proved that $h'(a) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty 2x e^{-x^2}e^{2ax} dx$. Another way is to integrate $\int_0^b \int_{-\infty}^\infty 2x e^{-x^2}e^{2ax} dxda= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_0^b 2x e^{-x^2}e^{2ax}da dx= h(a)-h(0)$, and since the integrand is continuous it means $h'(b) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h}\int_b^{b+h} \int_{-\infty}^\infty 2x e^{-x^2}e^{2ax} dxda= \int_{-\infty}^\infty 2x e^{-x^2}e^{2bx} dx$.

Integrating by parts $$h'(a) =\int_{-\infty}^\infty 2x e^{-x^2}e^{2ax} dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}2a e^{2ax} dx= 2a h(a)$$ Thus $$\log h(a) = \log h(0)+\int_0^a \frac{h'(b)}{h(b)} db = \log h(0)+\int_0^a 2b db = \log h(0) + a^2$$ and $ h(a) = e^{a^2} h(0)=e^{a^2}\sqrt{\pi}$.

About the first part,  note in real analysis $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} dx =\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x-a)^2} dx$ is correct only for $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

In complex analysis it is correct for $a \in \mathbb{C}$ when using the Cauchy integral theorem.

Another method is for $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $h(a) =e^{a^2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x-a)^2} dx=e^{a^2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} dx= \sqrt{\pi} e^{a^2}$.
Since $h(a)-\sqrt{\pi} e^{a^2}$ is analytic for $a \in \mathbb{C}$ and non-constant analytic functions have only isolated zeros and $h(a)-\sqrt{\pi} e^{a^2} = 0$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$, then $h(a)-\sqrt{\pi} e^{a^2} = 0$ for $a \in \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(t)$ be given by the integral

$$f(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos(xt)\,dx\tag1$$

Differentiating $(1)$ reveals

$$f'(t)=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty xe^{-x^2}\sin(xt)\,dx\tag2$$

Integrating by parts the integral on the right-hand side of $(2)$ with $u=\sin(xt)$ and $v=-\frac12e^{-x^2}$ yields

$$\begin{align}
f'(t)&=- \frac12t\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos(xt)\,dx\\\\
&=-\frac12 tf(t)\tag3
\end{align}$$

Hence $f(t)$ satisfies the ODS

$$f'(t)+\frac12 tf(t)=0\tag4$$

subject to the initial condition $f(0)=\sqrt \pi$.  It is straightforward to solve $(4)$ subject to the initial condition.  Proceeding we find that

$$f(t)=\sqrt \pi e^{-t^2/4} \tag5$$

Differentiating $(5)$, we obtain

$$f'(t)=-\frac{\sqrt \pi}2 te^{-t^2/2}$$